# Excel Spreadsheet - If Email Address in Column B Exists in Column A Say "Match Found" in Column C

Tags: excel

I have two columns of email addresses in an excel spreadsheet.  I need to know if an email address in column B exists in column A.

If an email address in column B does exist in column A, I'd like it to read "match found" next to the corresponding email address in column C.

I'm playing around with something I found here on StackOverflow that looks something like:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP
```

But I can't get it to work (I'm not a complete newb to Excel, but more advance formulas I'm not very familiar with unfortunately)

Comment: Try =VLOOKUP(A:A,B1,1,FALSE)

Answer (score 6):

You could try this (in `C1`):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)>0, "Match Found","")
```

Starting in `C1`, this will take the email in `B1` and count how many times it appears in column `A`. If the result is > 0, `Match Found` will be shown; otherwise, the cell will be empty (`""`).

Although you can find many uses for them, usually a `VLOOKUP` will be used in cases where you want to look up one value and return a corresponding value in the same row but in a different column (so for instance, if you had a table of email addresses and first names, and a separate list of emails, you could use a `VLOOKUP` next to the separate list of emails to 'look up' an email in the main table, find the match row and then return the second column in the table, which would be the name). [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) is the official documentation.

Comment: Worked great. Changed =IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)>0, B1,"") so the cleaned email appeared in the new column so I could then grab only unmatched emails.